# find kth good number

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Recently, In a competitive coding exam I got this question -

A good number is number whose sum of digits is divisible by 5. example - 5 (5), 14 (1+4), 19(1+9), 23(2+3)

Question is - you are provided a integer `n` and another integer `k` you have to find kth good number greater the  n.

Constraints - `1<k<10^9`

Sample test 1 -

```
input: n = 6, k = 5
output: 32
Explanation: After 6 good numbers are  - 14, 19, 23, 28, 32 (5th is 32)
```

Sample test 2 -

```
input: n = 5, k = 1
output: 14
Explanation: 5 is 1st good number but we need greater than 5 so ans is 14
```

I have tried it with native approach i.e for each number greater then n checking if it is good and loop until I found k good numbers, here is my code -

```
def solve(n,k):
    n+=1
    count = 0
    while count<k:
        if sum(map(int,str(n)))%5==0:
            count+=1
        n+=1
    return n-1
```

but above code was gave me TLE, how to do it in better time complexity, I have searched on internet for similar question but unable to find, help.

Comment: Added an answer with digit dynamic-programming.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with a simple question:

1. I give you a list of five *consecutive* numbers. How many of those numbers are divisible by 5? (I'm not talking abouts sums of digits yet. Just the numbers, like 18, 19, 20, 21, 22.

No problem there, right? So a slightly different question:

2. In a list of ten consecutive numbers, how many are divisible by 5?

Still pretty easy, no? Now let's look at your "good" numbers. We'll start by introducing the function **digit_sum**(*n*), which is the sum of the digits in *n*. For now, we don't need to write that function; we just need to know it exists. And here's another simple question:

3. If *n* is a number which does not end in the digit 9 and *s* is **digit_sum**(*n*), what is **digit_sum**(*n*+1)? (Try a few numbers if that's not immediately clear.) (Bonus question: why does it matter whether the last digit is 9? Or to put it another way, why doesn't it matter which digit other than 9 is at the end? What's special about 9?)

Ok, almost there. Let's put these two ideas together:

4. Suppose *n* ends with 0. How many of the ten numbers **digit_sum**(*n*), **digit_sum**(*n*+1), **digit_sum**(*n*+2), … **digit_sum**(*n*+9) are divisible by 5? (See question 2).

Does that help you find a quick way to compute the *k*th good number after *n*? Hopefully, the answer is yes. Now you just need to generalise a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your digits algorithm is too time consuming? try this:

```
def digits(n):
  sum = 0
  while n:
    n, r = divmod(n, 10)
    sum += r
  return sum
  
def solve(n,k):
  n+=1
  count = 0
  while count<k:
    if digits(n)%5==0:
      count+=1
    n+=1
  return n-1
```

still it’s a trivial solution, and always you can run it offline and just submit a lookups table.

And here is a link for this sequence: http://oeis.org/A227793

Comment: I think we have to think something new, other than this native approach, may be yours is a bit faster but it will also TLE see the constraints you can't do that in O(n)

Comment: @PankajSharma yeah you are right it’s still a trivial solution

Comment: @PankajSharma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem I hope that this could help? it's kind of a number partition problem? treating n as (x[0],x[1], ..., x[k]) and find the number of solutions that x[0] +... + x[k] = 5 or x[0] +... + x[k] = 10 or x[0] +... + x[k] = 15 and so on...

Comment: @PankajSharma or with the fact that Number of non-negative integral solutions of equation x1 + x2 + …… + xn = k is given by (n+k-1)! / (n-1)!*k! ? Using it should be able to skip some candidates number. Still I have no clear clue now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a digit dynamic-program that can answer how many such numbers we can find from 1 to the parameter, `k`. The function uses `O(num_digits)` search space. We could use it to search for the `k`th good number with binary search.

The idea generally is that the number of good numbers that include digit `d` in the `i`th position, and have a prefix mod 5 of `mod1` so far, is equal to the count of valid digit-suffixes that have the complementary mod, `mod2`, so that `(mod1 + mod2) mod 5 = 0`.

JavaScript code comparing with brute force:

```js
function getDigits(k){
  const result = [];
  while (k){
    result.push(k % 10);
    k = ~~(k / 10);
  }
  return result.reverse();
}

function g(i, mod, isK, ds, memo){
  const key = String([i, mod, isK]);
  
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key];
    
  let result = 0;
  const max = isK ? ds[i] : 9;
    
  // Single digit
  if (i == ds.length-1){
    for (let j=0; j<=max; j++)
      result += (j % 5 == mod);
    return memo[key] = result;
  }
  
  // Otherwise
  for (let j=0; j<=max; j++){
    const m = j % 5;
    const t = (5 + mod - m) % 5;
    const next = g(i+1, t, isK && j == max, ds, memo);
    result += next;
  }
  
  return memo[key] = result;
}

function f(k){
  if (k < 10)
    return (k > 4) & 1;
  
  const ds = getDigits(k);
  const memo = {};
  let result = -1;
  
  for (let i=0; i<=ds[0]; i++){
    const m = i % 5;
    const t = (5 - m) % 5;
    const next = g(1, t, i==ds[0], ds, memo);
    result += next;
  }
  
  return result;
}

function bruteForce(k){
  let result = 0;
  //let ns = [];
  
  for (let i=1; i<=k; i++){
    const ds = getDigits(i);
    const sum = ds.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    if (!(sum % 5)){
      //ns.push(i);
      result += 1;
    }
  }
  //console.log(ns);
  return result;
}

var k = 3000;

for (let i=1; i<k; i++){
  const _bruteForce = bruteForce(i);
  const _f = f(i);
  if (_bruteForce != _f){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(_bruteForce);
    console.log(_f);
    break;
  }
}

console.log('Done.');
```